# How to create list that counts number of games played by team, and stores it in each row in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Say I have two columns like this:

```
home_team    away_team
    SWE        DEN
    NOR        GER
    SWE        NOR
    GER        DEN
    GER        SWE
```

and want to create two new columns that count the games played by the home_team and away_team, like this:

```
home_team    away_team    games_HomeTeam   games_AwayTeam
    SWE         DEN                  1                1
    NOR         GER                  1                1 
    SWE         NOR                  2                2 
    GER         DEN                  2                2
    GER         FRA                  3                1
```

Comment: I don't see a correlation between your `home_team` and `games_HomeTeam`. Do you mean games WON by home/away team? Even then, your numbers don't make sense to me. What do the numbers in your `home_team` and `away_team` mean?? Is that the final score of the game? Wouldn't both teams have exactly the number of games played as there are rows?

Comment: The numbers in home_team/away_team are just "teams", let's say their ID

Comment: Please provide us with atleast a code example of what you have tried so far

Comment: @MisterButter In that case how is games_homeTeam calculated? If you're saying that the home_team # is the team ID, where does the games_ number come from? Shouldn't it be ID specific?

Comment: Your explanation is still insufficient for us to know how to calculate values for this dataframe... What does each row represent? One game per row? Then why are you creating an entire column to keep track of how many games are played? And if it's games played by a home team, does it matter which team? If not, then the number is still just the number of rows, as there's always one home team and one away team every single game...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
flatten = [e for p in zip(df.home_team, df.away_team) for e in p]
counts = pd.DataFrame((pd.Series(flatten).groupby(flatten).cumcount() + 1).values.reshape(-1, 2),
                      columns=['games_HomeTeam', 'games_AwayTeam'])

print(pd.concat([df, counts], axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
   home_team  away_team  games_HomeTeam  games_AwayTeam
0          1          2               1               1
1          3          4               1               1
2          1          3               2               2
3          2          4               2               2
4          1          5               3               1
```

First flatten the two columns, then group and cumcount followed by a reshape. Finally concat with `df`.

Comment: I have no idea how you were able to infer what OPs intentions were with this, but bravo.

Comment: @KuboMD Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah thank you, worked like a charm, and really sorry about not providing an adequate explanation. I couldn't wrap my head around how to explain it. Couldn't even figure out how I would do it in excel.

Comment: Another option to flatten `df.T.melt().value.values`. Nice one!